# What is the difference between File System and File Management in an operating system?

Tags: operating-system, filesystems, kernel, file-management

I’ve found about file management explanations and file system explanations and “file system is part of file management” explanations. But I am wondering if they are the same or two different things? Because I cannot seem to find an article about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A modern Operating System, to be portable, must be file system independent.  i.e.: It should not matter what type of storage format a given media device contains.  At the same time, a media device must contain a specific type of storage format to contain files and folders, and at the same time be Operating System independent.

For example, an OS should be able to handle any file locally, allowing the actual transfer of these files from physical media to the OS (and visa-versa) to be managed by the file system manager.  Therefore, an OS can be completely independent of how the file was stored on the media.

With this in mind, there are at least two layers, usually more, of management between the file being viewed and the file on the physical media.  Here is a (simple) list of layers that might be used from top down.

1. OS App viewing the file
2. OS File Manager
3. OS File System Manager (allowing multiple file systems)
4. Specific File System Driver
5. Media Device Driver

When a call to read a file is made, the app (1) calls the OS File manager (2), which in turn--due to the opening of the file--calls the correct OS File System Manager (3), which then calls the Specific File System Driver (4), which then calls the Media Device Driver (5) for the actual access.

Please note that any or all could have a working cache manager which means calls are processed and returned without calling lower layers.  e.g.: each read more than requested in anticipation of another read.

By having multiple layers like this, you can have any (physical) file system and/or media device you wish and the OS would be none the wiser.  All you need is a media driver for the specific physical device and a file system manager for the physical format of the contents of the media.  As long as these layers all support the common service calls, any format of media and content on that media will be allowed by the OS.